# Automatically change the page password for more than one page

Tags: password

This relates to this post - [Automatically change page password](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174814/automatically-change-page-password)

Can this be applied to multiple pages instead of just one?

I have changed the slug to the below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$slug = array('page-one','page-two','page-three','page-four','page-five'); // Edit this post slug to your needs!
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work on multiple posts, your options are either

1. write the 'where' clause for the update as a SQL 'IN', e.g. using [the answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156527/wpdb-update-multiple-rows-like-in-in-normal-sql) - this will use the same newly-generated password for every post
2. add a loop and call $wpdb->update individually for each post - this will either make a new password for each or use the same password depending on how you write the loop

   ```
   $slugs = array('page-one','page-two','page-three','page-four','page-five');

   global $wpdb;
   foreach( $slugs as $slug ) {
       // This bit as before
       $wpdb->update(
           $wpdb->posts,
           array( 'post_password' => uniqid() ),
           array( 'post_name'     => $slug    ),
           array( '%s' ),
           array( '%s' )
       );
   }
   ```
3. just do this directly in SQL instead?

   ```
   UPDATE wp_posts
     SET  post_password = '....'
   WHERE  post_name IN ('page-one','page-two','page-three','page-four','page-five');
   ```

   I think this is by far the easiest, but obviously take a database backup first if you're not confident. You'll have to generate your own passwords somehow here though whereas the other methods will generate something random for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks Rup that worked - I was actually in the process of doing point 2 - but had the foreach loop in the wrong place so perfect timing.